# Env variables in Shopify extension checkout

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, shopify, checkout

I have a Shopify checkout extension that calls a server endpoint. This server endpoint differs for local, staging and production. I am trying to introduce ci/cd in GitHub Actions for the extension by following this tutorial: https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/tools/cli/ci-cd. However, I don't if it's possible or how to pass in an env var or to the extension.

```
// I want this to change depending on the environment
export const apiUrl = "https://staging_endpoint.com";
```

The extension runs in a sandbox on the browser so it doesn't have access to environment variables since it's not a node process. The extension is a typescript and react with the following tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "types": ["react"]
  },
  "include": ["./src"]
}
```

And this is the extension.toml:

```
api_version = "2023-07"

[[extensions]]
type = "ui_extension"
name = "zipr-discount-ext"
handle = "zipr-discount-ext"

[[extensions.targeting]]
module = "./src/index.tsx"
target = "purchase.checkout.block.render"
[extensions.capabilities]
network_access = true
block_progress = false
api_access = true
```

The shopify app frontend is built using `vite` and these are the package versions:

```
    "@shopify/app": "^3.50.0",
    "@shopify/cli": "^3.50.0",
    "@shopify/ui-extensions": "^2023.10.0",
    "@shopify/ui-extensions-react": "^2023.10.0",
    "@shopify/shopify-api": "^7.3.1",
```

I have tried introducing a dotenv package like so:

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();
const myVariable = process.env.REACT_APP_MY_VARIABLE;
```

Or using VITE__

But obviously this won't work cause we don't have process.env in the browser.

Comment: Adam, did you find a solution to this?